# Strategies for displaying large dataset in Android RecyclerView

Tags: android, performance, android-recyclerview, memory-efficient

RecyclerView implementations usually have the following approach:

- create RecyclerAdapter holding the data set or a reference to it, e.g. List
- attach adapter and LayoutManager to RecyclerView
- call setItems (or equivalent) on adapter to refresh content
- optionally add pagination+endless scroll to be able to gradually load more content small chinks at a time

This uses the power of RecyclerView and ViewHolder to display huge datasets efficiently. However, it does not solve the issue of storing the dataset in memory which is what my question is about.

Imagine I have 1 million items in my dataset and have implemented pagination+endless scroll. If I'm on the last page, in order for the RecyclerView to be able to display the items we would have to store all 1 million items in a list in the adapter and use that list with the relevant RecyclerAdapter methods.

Is there a more efficient way of doing that? My initial thoughts were to have some sort of sliding window based approach where we'd keep a fixed number of pages in memory and have a two-way endless scroll implementation where the next/prev page window gets updated as the scroll "viewport" changes while the user scrolls. Unsure if that would affect scrolling performance...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

consider [android's paging library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging)

It works in terms of loading data *as pages* and not just loading everything into memory. When scrolling, it'll load the appropriate pages you tell it to, so it wouldn't have to keep everything in memory, you could pass in appropriate keys for where to retrieve data and the pagination library will handle that for you.

It supports reading from a database as well as to read from the network or a hybrid of the two, so it should be fine for whichever you need

---

I suppose it's worth saying that, if you already have your own implementation going, you could also try to mimic this behavior. If you have a way of knowing that a user has reached a certain threshold within the data you're displaying, you could load the next/previous page yourself, then just manage the amount of data you keep in memory yourself. one page up/down might be sufficient, anything more you could clear out your own local memory

Comment: Ha! I didn't know about that library, seems like it's made to do exactly this. Even supports preloading out of view pages. Will wait a bit before marking answer as correct to see other suggestions. Thanks

Comment: i'm not _exactly_ sure what the state of the library is, but i've used it twice, the first time was a bit chaotic, but version 3 (which is in alpha currently) was a lot simpler, so  perhaps try that, for what it's worth

Comment: either way, glad this could help

Comment: For sure worth trying, setup in the docs looks easy enough 

Comment: from what i can remember, the "standard" paging library was a bit complicated, there were 3 different types of DataSource factories to create (or something like that) and i found it a bit confusing, but Paging 3 does away with this and just lets you handle it yourself, but this is all _entirely_ my own opinion, i can confirm that the library works really really well though, i've seen and used it previously

Comment: Cool, I had a feeling there would be something that handles similar use cases already. Most examples I found only show the vanilla RecyclerView setup so this is definitely promising